# Installing MySQL on Amazon EC2 Instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

So I installed MySQL using `yum install mysql` on an Amazon EC2 Micro instance using the **Basic 64-bit Amazon Linux AMI 2010.11.1 Beta** AMI.  I try to connect to MySQL using the command `mysql` but I get the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)
```

I can't understand why this is happening. I seem to be the same as [this question here](https://serverfault.com/questions/196688/cannot-connect-to-mysql-on-ec2-instance). What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server may not be installed, try

```
yum install mysql-server
```

it will start as part of the installation process. Use

```
chkconfig mysqld on
```

to have the server run after a reboot.

Comment: Ha, didn't install the mysql-server part. Good catch, thanks a bunch.

Comment: No problem, easy mistake to make :)